# Federated IBMid SSO bypass one time

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I am attempting to programmatically create federated user account and setup that user account using automation.

The reason for this is because we would want to create customized user environments (by logging in the user).

By Default when a domain is federated at IBM, the user account at that domain is not created, the user has to login for the account to be created. See notes from Documentation:

[image]

I want to have the user created so automation scripts can provision services and resource using Schematics SDK (Workspace)

I found that the user can be logged in and trigger account creation by using CLI
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-federated_id
The program is that when using CLI, it prompts for a one-time code for SSO logins (federated)

It says to avoid the one-time codes for automation scripts, you have to use API key
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-federated_id#api_key

However you can only get the API key after the user has been created. Which brings me to this question.. how do we get the API key before getting the user logged, is there a way programmatically or what have others done in python to get around this one-time token prompt to log in the federated user so that their environment and account is created for schematics and other automation scripts to deploy instances etc.?

Comment: Could you add more details of how your company is set up? That should be a matter of integration and an IBM support ticket. It seems like a chicken and egg issue and default security settings.

Comment: When we do domain federation, any user with user@domain.com should be able to login.

The problem is that with a domain federation, the accounts are not created on the account right away, only when the user actually attempts to login (JIT provisioning from IBM Cloud)

Comment: JIT makes sense for large enterprises. IBM Cloud seems to have an onboarding service for large accounts. Are you using that and its support?